# List of possible errors for AssignQualification operation (Mechanical Turk)

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I would like a list of all the possible error messages the `AssignQualification` operation returns. For example 1 of the possible errors is: `AWS.MechanicalTurk.QualificationTypeDoesNotExist` which has the message "QualificationType 000000000000000000L0 does not exist (1287717938474)".

I just need a list of all the possible errors this service can throw back at me.

Comment: That's the only one I've seen. You might want to try asking this [on the developer forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=11&start=0).

Comment: Thanks for your help Thomas, I did that. Let's see if I get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research of my own, and figured it out. Here it is for anyone who is interested...

```
AWS.MechanicalTurk.QualificationTypeDoesNotExist
```

Self explanatory, for some reason the Qualification Type did not get created.

```
AWS.MechanicalTurk.QualificationAlreadyExists
```

This one is really confusing, it actually means the worker already has the qualification.

```
AWS.MechanicalTurk.InvalidParameterValue
```

The worker ID does not exist.

Thanks.